# Filetransfer over Socket in Java, wont go out of while-loop

Tags: java, sockets, stream

I am trying to create a simple server-client-program where the user can upload and download files. I have got the Sockets and Streams to work, and I can upload a file to the server. But whenever one file has been uploaded the Server-side seems to get stuck in the loop that reads the streams and forwards it to the Server-file.

Server Code:

```
    InputStream in = clientSocket.getInputStream();

    String filePath = "......."
            + op[1];

    System.out.println(op[0] + ": " + filePath);

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filePath);

    byte[] bytes = new byte[16*1024];

    int count;

    while ((count = in.read(bytes)) > 0) {
        out.write(bytes, 0, count);
    }
```

Client Code:

```
    String filePath = "...."
            + path;
    System.out.println("Attempting: " + filePath);

    dos = new DataOutputStream(serverSocket.getOutputStream());
    fis = new FileInputStream(filePath);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

    while (fis.read(buffer) > 0) {
        dos.write(buffer);
    }

    dos.flush();
    fis.close();
```

The problem is that the program gets stuck at the while-loop, so the Server can not perform anything else. There are no errors or anything...

Answer (score 1):

You never close the stream on the client side. Add `dos.close()` after `dos.flush()`!

Comment: Thanks, that got the program to exit the while-loop. However the Socket-connection between the Client and the Server is also closed. I would like to have a program where i can upload 3 files in a row and if I close the socket after each upload i would have to connect again. Is there a way around this, or should I just connect to the server for each  request?

Comment: You may want to define a protocol that allows the server to recognize file boundaries. For example, you can setup your stream so that before each file you send the file size. The server read loop will need to take this into account. 

I assume that you are doing this an a learning exercise since various file transfer protocol with "off the shelf" Java implementation exist.